# Making a 3D graphics engine, my Translation matrix doesn't work for positions equal to 0

Tags: c++, matrix, 3d, transformation

Hi I'm making a 3D graphics engine for an assignment that is due later tonight, it's going smoothly at the moment except I'm loading a cube model from an .obj file, the positions start at 0.

My transformation matrix works for numbers that don't = 0. I mean if X = 0 and I try to translate it by 10 on the X Axis, it returns 0.

Matrix * Vector:

```
Vec4 Mat4::operator*(const Vec4& v) const
{
    Vec4 tmp(0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    tmp.x = (this->data[0] * v.x) + (this->data[4] * v.y) + (this->data[8] * v.z) + (this->data[12] * v.w);
    tmp.y = (this->data[1] * v.x) + (this->data[5] * v.y) + (this->data[9] * v.z) + (this->data[13] * v.w);
    tmp.z = (this->data[2] * v.x) + (this->data[6] * v.y) + (this->data[10] * v.z) + (this->data[14] * v.w);
    tmp.w = (this->data[3] * v.x) + (this->data[7] * v.y) + (this->data[11] * v.z) + (this->data[15] * v.w);
    return tmp;

}
```

Translate Matrix:

```
Mat4 Mat4::translate(float x, float y, float z)
{
    Mat4 tmp;

    tmp.data[12] = x;
    tmp.data[13] = y;
    tmp.data[14] = z;

    return tmp;
}
```

A Mat4 class by default is an identity matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "My transformation matrix works for numbers that != 0"? Elaborate on the error you are getting.

Comment: I mean if X = 0 and I try to translate it by 10 on the X Axis, it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

#### It is too late now, but... it might be helpful to know the following:

A vector strictly equal to **0.0** (e.g. <**0**,**0**,**0**,**0**>) cannot be translated using matrix multiplication and technically should not be considered a position in this context. In fact, such a vector is not even representative of a direction because it has **0** length. It is simply **zero**; there are not a whole lot of uses for a vector that cannot be rotated or translated.

You can ***rotate*** vectors with **0.0** for the W coordinate, but the value **0.0** for W ***prevents translation***.

#### Generally you want a W coordinate of **1.0** for spatial (*e.g.* position) vectors and **0.0** for directional (*e.g.* normal).

If you want to understand this better, you need to consider how your 4x4 matrix is setup. The first 3 rows or columns (depending on which convention you use) store rotation, and the 4th stores translation.

#### Consider how translation is applied when you multiply your matrix and vector:

```
x = ... + (this->data[12] * v.w);
y = ... + (this->data[13] * v.w);
z = ... + (this->data[14] * v.w);
w = ... + (this->data[15] * v.w);
```

If `v.w` is **0.0**, then translation evaluates to **0.0** for all coordinates.